# pygame : while runs once and stops

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a program that draw six number. please help me.
When (A)button is pressed, it runs once and stops. What should I do if I want to run it many times?

```
numT = []
team = random.randint(1, 6)  

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == event.key == ord('a'):
        for i in range(6):
            while team in numT:
                team = random.randint(1, 6)
            numT.append(team)

        num1 = font.render(str(numT), True, (255, 255, 255))

screen.blit(num1, (200, 117))
```

The result that I want(on the pygame screen) : example

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a new sequence, you have to clear the old one with `numT = []` or `numT.clear()`.
However, the conde can be simplified using [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        numT = list(range(1, 7))
        random.shuffle(numT)
        num1 = font.render(str(numT), True, (255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: Thank you. thanks to you, I solved problem